# Google Analytics API Quota Error Timeout

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm currently creating a project that uses the Google-Analytics-API and have just received the following error:

> Quota Error: Number of recent failed reporting API requests is too high, please implement exponential back off.

My questions is, how long do I need to wait before trying again? Does this 'reset' so to speak? Right now, the endpoint times out instantly and gives me the above message.. It's been working fine this whole time however.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This depends a little on which quota error you are getting.  there is a list here [errors](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/errors) and they also add new ones.

its most liekly one of the flood protecion ones.  In which case you should implement exponential backoff.

1. Make a request to the API
2. Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
3. Wait 1s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
4. Retry request
5. Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
6. Wait 2s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
7. Retry request
8. Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
9. Wait 4s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
10. Retry request
11. Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
12. Wait 8s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
13. Retry request
14. Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
15. Wait 16s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
16. Retry request
17. If you still get an error, stop and log the error.

You can read the full list of errors here [errors](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/errors#error_table)

There is another quota if you send a request that returns an error for example requesting dimensions and metrics that cant be mixed.  If you keep doing it then you can be blocked normally for a few hours.  Check Google developer console under Enabled APIs and services you can see how many errors are you are getting. try and stay under 4%